# Create CLOB property from JSON

Tags: java, sql, json, spring, clob

I have Entity **imported like a Maven dependency**, looks like this(simplified)

```
@Entity
public class Person extends Base {

    private String name;

    private Clob biography;
//Getters and setters
```

And I receive this JSON with method POST

```
{"name":"John Doe",
"biography":"dragonborn"}
```

And I got this error

```
"status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
    "message": "Could not read document: Can not construct instance of java.sql.Clob, 
problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information\n at
 [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@39e31d6a; line: 2, column: 13] (through reference chain: com.example.Person[\"biography\"]); 
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
Can not construct instance of java.sql.Clob, 
problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information\n 
at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@39e31d6a; line: 2, column: 13] (through reference chain: com.example.Person[\"biography\"])",
    "path": "/persons"
```

If "biography" was String, Person is created.
How can i convert JSON property to java.sql.Clob property?
The best solution will tuning ObjectMapper, but i would be glad to hear any advices. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
@Lob
String biography
```

And in DDL for database initiate column as CLOB