# Inserting a JSON as a column in teradata using spring-boot

Tags: json, spring-boot, teradata, insert-update

I am working on a spring boot application where i need to insert data into teradata DB.
My table consists of three columns : id, Name, Json_data
where id and name are varchar, Json_data is JSON

i have a pojo class with id and name as String type and JSON_data as clob 
which is working perfectly to retrive the data (GET Operations)

I am getting the following error  while inserting the data from postman

```
2017-09-06 05:39:29.186  WARN 15516 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of java.sql.Clob: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.sql.Clob: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1eee791; line: 9, column: 15] (through reference chain: com.model.SampleModel["jsondata"])
```

Can anyone explain which is the best way to insert the sample data from my rest API My JSON looks as below:

```
{
    "id": "23",
    "name": "Navatha",
    "jsondata": "{\"Notes\": \"sample Note\",\"BU\": \"BFS\",\"NumberOfFields\": \"4\"}"
}
```

Comment: have a look into this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906458/create-clob-property-from-json

Comment: Thanks alot.. it worked

Comment: I just added the response here to be useful for other people from comunity

Comment: could do you validate teh response i did? Then is useful for other members. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add the annotation Lob in your entity

```
@Lob
String jsondata
```

Comment: @navatha great, could do you validate and aprove the response? So its useful for other members :)